# Routing One Pod’s packet to another Pod

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, containers, cluster-computing

I am trying to deploy a pod hosting IPSec functionality lets say IPsec pod.
This IPsec pod is responsible for encrypting all the packets it receives, in ESP mode and send it to a security gateway inside the IPsec tunnel. Any other pods requiring IPsec functionality should be routing their packets directly to this IPsec pod for the sake of tunneling their packets.
I have looked into weavenet, flannel, canal CNIs, but we could not come up with the way to realize this requirement.

Problem Diagram:
[image: Problem Diagram]

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

**Cluster information:**
Kubernetes version: 1.17.0)
Cloud being used: Bare-metal
Installation method:
Host OS: Cent OS-7
CNI and version: flannel (latest)
CRI and version: Docker 1.13.1

Regards,
Shubham

Comment: This would have to be directly supported by your CNI plugin. Some do support various flavors of network encryption, check the docs for more info.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Packet generated from pod1 has pod 2 as destination IP. I want to route the packet generated from pod 1 directly to IPSEC pod for encryption, there onwards to security gw. Security gw  should decrypt the packet and decrypted packet should go to  destination POD2. Is there a possible way within kubernetes to handle this scenario

Comment: Does it has to be IPsec? There is alternative way of achieving similar effect with istio and calico zero trust network configuration and it can automatically work on all pods in specific namespace. https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.10/security/adopt-zero-trust#requirements-of-a-zero-trust-network

Comment: Thanks Piotr! Ipsec is what we required for our app. If its not a possible solution then we may look into other possible ways! Other possible solutions are welcome.